polycount increased too much if using subdivide modifier
I was creating a character. For the body, before subdivision, the triangle count is 6.9k. After subdivision, it increases to 110k. What can I do to make the character look smooth without significantly increasing the polycount?

Hello, don't apply the modifier!

If you don't apply the modifier the real amount of polygones will stay the same, you can verify it if you switch to Edit mode. Don't apply the modifier if you don't have any good reason to do it. Also, to make the object look smoother, you can right click in Object mode and Shade Smooth.

i see. so under what conditions should I apply the modifier. for example I want to rig and animate the character. do I need to apply it?

no, don't apply, it will be much lighter to animate a low-poly mesh, also make sure that the Subdivision Surface modifier is under the Armature modifier
